# RunProcess[] fails after some hundred times, BUG?

Tags: external-calls

The following fails (and sometimes causes Mathematica 10.0.0.0 to crash) on macOS 10.12.3:

```
  For[i = 1, i <= 400, i++,
  RunProcess[$SystemShell, All, "echo 5  
    exit  
    "];  
  ];
```

The error message being: `"Cannot open in:200"`
Reducing the number of iterations makes it work again.
Any suggestions?

**EDIT**:
`ulimit -u` outputs 709
`ulimit -n` outputs 256

I believe this has to do with file descriptors, because Mathematica fails to open `in` which  believe is meant to be `stdin` of the process, but even running `sysctl -w kern.maxfilesperproc=20000` does not fix the issue...

---

This is effectively the same as [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/error-when-implementing-startprocess-in-loops-do-while-table/63033#63033) and is fixed in more recent releases.

Comment: Whenever asking about problems like this, please mention your *exact* version of Mathematica.

Comment: I can produce a similar error on my linux box (v10.1). `StartProcess::nffil : File not found during RunProcess`.  It takes more than 400 calls (a few thousand).   It shouldnt be a process limit issue since each `RunProcess` finishes before the next one starts.

Comment: 10.0.0 was a rather buggy version.  Many bugs were fixed in 10.0.2, so consider installing that bugfix release regardless of this problem.  That said, I can see various errors after about 1500-2000 iterations with 10.0.2.  With 10.3.1 or with 11.0.1 I do not see the problem.

Comment: This reminds me of a problem report I received about MaTeX, which I suspected to be caused by a RunProcess bug, perhaps triggered by too many invocations. That was with v11.0.  However, neither I nor the reporter was able to reproduce the problem a second time.

Comment: The problem might be the same one identified [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61726/error-when-implementing-startprocess-in-loops-do-while-table/63033#63033)